# Trying to design App in portrait mode for desktop(13.3") but option is not available in uwp

Tags: xaml, uwp

I'm trying to design  app in portrait mode in UWP but option is not available .
Any idea to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this target what you're trying to achieve is not advisable as Universal Windows Platform is for all device families and it's not advisable to make the UI of the application specific to only a single device type. Although there are no particular ways to achieve this, there are many workarounds,

1. Create a `DesignHeight` and `DesignWidth` for your application so that the Designer of visual studio knows what specific screen pixel size you're designing for.
2. Use MaxWidth and MaxHeight in your application to ensure the application doesn't use full screen sizes, use height/width properties of your page to not make the app size resizable (highly not recommended).
3. If Portrait view is what you must have then you can set the max width of your `RootGrid` and if the app screen size increases your maxWidth centre align your content. (this can be done by setting the `MaxWidth = 900` property and the `horrizontalAlignment` property to stretch) (See the Zomato App on windows 10 desktop for a good idea)

---

To Set the designHeight/Width:

```
d:DesignHeight="500"
d:DesignWidth="400"
```

use the above in your `page` tag

---

For The point 2:
use `Height="900" Width="450"` in your Page Tag

---

For the Point 3:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MaxWidth="900">
</Grid>
```